How to implement react native webrtc Screen Recording and upload chunk in aws s3 in React Native
I'm trying to implement screen recording in my React Native app using WebRTC, and I want to upload the recorded video in chunks to AWS S3. I’m facing challenges with both the recording and the chunked upload process. Any guidance or sample code would be appreciated!
Challenges:

How can I efficiently handle chunked uploads?
Should I convert the blob to a file before uploading?
Any best practices for managing AWS
S3 uploads in React Native?

Additional Information:

I am targeting both iOS and Android platforms.
My goal is to maintain good performance during recording and uploading without blocking the
UI.

